# How to create custom view programmatically in swift having controls text field, button etc

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, custom-view

I am trying to access the `MyCustomView` from another class using the following code in ViewController.swift ..

```
var view = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

.. in the `viewDidLoad` method. The problem is the view does not get initialized in the simulator.

I have already set class in storyboard for the current ViewController.

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {
    var label: UILabel = UILabel()
    var myNames = ["dipen","laxu","anis","aakash","santosh","raaa","ggdds","house"]

    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addCustomView()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addCustomView() {
        label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 10, 200, 100)
        label.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "test label"
        label.hidden=true
        self.addSubview(label)

        var btn: UIButton = UIButton()
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(50, 120, 200, 100)
        btn.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
        btn.setTitle("button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "changeLabel", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(btn)

        var txtField : UITextField = UITextField()
        txtField.frame = CGRectMake(50, 250, 100,50)
        txtField.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        self.addSubview(txtField)
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling self.view.addSubview(myCustomView) when you initialize it?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `CGRectZero` constant is equal to a rectangle at position `(0,0)` with zero width and height. This is fine to use, and actually preferred, if you use AutoLayout, since AutoLayout will then properly place the view.

But, I expect you do not use AutoLayout. So the most simple solution is to specify the size of the custom view by providing a frame explicitly:

```
customView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
self.view.addSubview(customView)
```

Note that you also need to use `addSubview` otherwise your view is not added to the view hierarchy.

Comment: thanks stefan...but saying CGRectZero and passing values does make anysense?

Comment: it makes sense if you use Auto Layout. Because in that case the actual placement and size of your view is determined by the Auto Layout Constraints and not by what you pass to the `init(frame:)` initializer.

Comment: Should that line read `customView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRect(top: 0, left: 0, width: 200, height: 50))` rather than `customView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectZero(top: 0, left: 0, width: 200, height: 50)`

Comment: If I have any constraints ( e.g. horizontal alignment X) added for customView, then there is a good change that they will peacefully override the frame of customView? Right?

Answer (score 36):

**Swift 3 / Swift 4** Update:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width - 10, height: 10))
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

Comment: Change `let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds` to `let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds.size`

Answer (score 10):

```
var customView = UIView()


@IBAction func drawView(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    customView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black     //give color to the view 
    customView.center = self.view.center  
    self.view.addSubview(customView)
       }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let viewDemo = UIView()
viewDemo.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
self.view.addSubview(viewDemo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
view = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

In this line you are trying to set empty rect for your custom view. That's why you cant see your view in simulator.

Comment: i have tried this way too var view = MyCustomView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 40, 500, 500))

Comment: and you need call method addSubview from controller view in viewDidLoad or somewhere. E.g. self.view.addSubview(yourView)

Comment: It could be anything other. Like you mark somewhere userInteractionEnabled or esle...

Comment: i just found if i call as MyCustomView(frame: CGRectZero),then the view gets frozen... :)