# How to add sliding animation to texts that is not fitting their space?

Tags: swift

Sometimes my texts are not fitting into their space on `UITableViewCell`. They are shrunk with three dots `...`. Is it possible to animate them like Phone App on Android? Like sliding automatically.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this class, it's fair easy and you can use just as a drop-in replacement for UILabel:

https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift

To convert UILabel to MarqueeLabel, if you using Storyboard, simply set the class of UILabel object to MarqueeLabel

[image: storyboard]

then setup parameters in viewDidLoad function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    titleLabel.type = .Continuous
    titleLabel.scrollDuration = 15.0
    titleLabel.animationCurve = .EaseInOut
    titleLabel.fadeLength = 20.0
    titleLabel.leadingBuffer = 30.0
    titleLabel.trailingBuffer = 20.0
}
```

Comment: please add the code here and give a short explanation on how this solves OP's question. Thanks!

Comment: How can I convert UILabel to MarqueeLabel?

Comment: I edited to use this with storyboard(xib), if you want init from code tell me.

Comment: I think I should initialize from code because I'm using prototype cells.

Comment: you can edit cells in storyboard. If you want initialise from code simply add this before this code: textLabel = MarqueeLabel() and setup constrains. the variable must be defined in class, not func, to avoid memory access error

Comment: but textLabel is a get-only property?

Comment: did you downloaded file from github and added it to your project?

Comment: adding this view to a view controller is like any other view, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030426/how-to-create-custom-view-programmatically-in-swift-having-controls-text-field